# Obtaining the highest terrain elevation BETWEEN two geographic points

Tags: geolocation, elevation

Does anyone know of an online service / API that can be used to get the highest terrain elevation between two geographic points?

I am using this to determine if sun is blocked by any terrain from the observers perspective at a specific time of day.

I can easily determine the viewers elevation, and I could use something like googles elevation API to walk the path along the correct bearing using distance intervals to create elevation profiles but this seems fairly costly from a query perspective

Thanks

Comment: Note that while basically impossible in 2012, in 2023 there's the option of doing this without needing an online service or API, by downloading a GIS dataset and doing local lookups with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any service or API for this, but...

You could use an improved search algorithm to reduce the number of queries required to determine the highest elevation. A "hill climbing" algorithm (yes, that's what it's literally called), would start at some point along the path, check the slope or points on either side of itself to see which direction is uphill, then move uphill in search of a local maximum. There's further optimizations that can be done to improve your selection of starting point and increase the chances you'll find the absolute maximum instead of just the top of one hill.

Some google searching for "hill climbing" algorithms should turn up some useful stuff.

Comment: I have thought about that, but it's still pretty query intensive though and google has a limit of 2500 query's which could be eaten quickly in my scenario

Comment: Gave you the points since you at least attempted an answer :-) The bottom line is there is no real great way to do this in an efficient manner (collect enough data) on a device.

Answer (score 2):

While normally tools/library requests are off topic, this is such a hard resource to find that it makes sense to -even a decade later- write a real answer.

While you might find Google Elevation mentioned in a number of other places, that became a paid service in 2018, but as of the time of writing, a free alternative is https://open-elevation.com API.

In order to get the maximum elevation between two points, take your two points, generate "as many points in between those two as makes for the fidelity you need" and then query the `https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup` API endpoint with that list of points as JSON payload:

```json
{
  "locations": [
    { "latitude": 48.756669, "longitude": -123.711434 },
    ...
    { "latitude": 48.849527, "longitude": -123.503368 }
  ]
}
```

This yields a JSON response with elevation data:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "latitude": 48.756669,
      "longitude": -123.711434,
      "elevation": 86
    },
    ... 
    {
      "latitude": 48.849527,
      "longitude": -123.503368,
      "elevation": 49
    }
  ]
}
```

Iterate to find the maximum `elevation`, and done.

Alternatively: **we can create our own lookup**, by downloading a GIS dataset and using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) either with python ([officially supported](https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html)) or using the unofficial [gdal-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal-async) in JavaScript (Which, honestly, I'd recommend for this purpose mostly because Node is so much faster than Python, for reasons I don't understand, but also don't *have* to understand. Just use whichever is faster and leave the arguments to others).

Of course, this doesn't make a lot of sense if you just need this once in a blue moon, but if need this a lot (e.g. you're writing a flightsim autopilot or something) then I'd recommend grabbing the [ALOS Wolrd 3D - 30m](https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/dataset/aw3d30/aw3d30_e.htm) dataset, which is a good tradeoff between filesize (150GB packed, 451GB unpacked) and geographical resolution (a 30x30 meter grid covering the entire planet's land surface), but you can always grab the 90m dataset instead, or even a completely different dataset, if you want a different tradeoff.

With all the tiles downloaded and unpacked, you can run your own lookups with barely any code:

In Python:

```py
import sys
from osgeo import gdal, osr
from math import ceil, floor
ALOS_VOID_VALUE = -9999

def get_tile_for(lat, lng):
    lat_dir = "N" if lat >= 0 else "S"
    lng_dir = "E" if lng >= 0 else "W"
    lat = floor(lat) if lat_dir == "N" else ceil(-lat)
    lng = floor(lng) if lng_dir == "E" else ceil(-lng)
    return "ALPSMLC30_%s%03d%s%03d_DSM.tif" % (lat_dir, lat, lng_dir, lng)

# get our coordinate
lat = sys.argv[1]
lng = sys.argv[2]

# load the tile for that coordinate
tile_path = get_tile_for(lat, long)
dataset = gdal.Open(tile_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
geodata = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

# map the GPS coordinate to its corresponding pixel index
pixel_to_gps = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
gps_to_pixel = gdal.InvGeoTransform(pixel_to_gps)
x, y = [int(v) for v in gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gps_to_pixel, lng, lat)]

# and we're done
elevation = int(self.grid[y][x])
if elevation != ALOS_VOID_VALUE:
    print(f'{lat},{lng} is not in the dataset')
else:
    print(f'elevation at {lat},{lng} is {elevation} meters')
```

And in JavaScript:

```js
import gdal from "gdal-async";
const { floor, ceil } = Math;
const ALOS_VOID_VALUE = -9999;

function getTileFor(lat, lng) {
  const latDir = lat >= 0 ? "N" : "S";
  const lngDir = lng >= 0 ? "E" : "W";
  lat = `` + (latDir == "N" ? floor(lat) : ceil(-lat));
  lng = `` + (lngDir == "E" ? floor(lng) : ceil(-lng));
  return `ALPSMLC30_${latDir}${lat.padStart(3, "0")}${lngDir}${lng.padStart(3,"0")}_DSM.tif`;
}

const lat = process.argv[1];
const long = process.argv[2];
const ds = gdal.open(getTileFor(lat, long));
const band = dataset.bands.get(1);
// slightly different transform code
const transform = gdal.CoordinateTransformation(WGS84, ds);
const { x, y } = transform.transformPoint(long, lat);
const elevation = band.pixels.get(x | 0, y | 0);

if (elevation === ALOS_VOID_VALUE) {
  console.log(`${lat},${long} is not in the dataset`);
} else {
  console.log(`elevation at ${lat},${long} is ${elevation} meters`);
}
```

And done. You can now trivially write your own server if you need a networked API endpoint, or turn it into a little package that you can import into a larger codebase.

And then we can do the same as with an online API, but so fast we could make it a block operation: generate the elevation values for the entire track from your start coordinate to your end coordinate, then run that list through `max()`/`Math.max()` and done: maximum elevation between two global positions.

(Just remember to add tile caching, because you can fit plenty of tiles in memory, and your lookup times will improve by some two orders of magnitude)

Comment: Admittedly not an expert, I am having some trouble finding where in your code you are accounting for the datetime and the subsolar point for determining the great circle path of all points along that path that are relevant to the OP, and the skysphere position of the sun at the observer's position.  Some help?

Comment: Neither of those matter if you have GPS coordinates. We just need to make sure we've applied the correct transforms for working in the GPS coordinate system. We're looking for elevation between two fixed points on the planet, that data is not influenced by where the planet is in relation to the sun (on land. The position of the sun and the moon of course heavily influence what the elevation of the ocean is at a given GPS coordinate, but that's not something that static elevation data can tell you)

Comment: "I am using this to determine if sun is blocked by any terrain from the observers perspective at a specific time of day."

Comment: The position of the sun, at a particular time of day, in order to see if it is blocked by some elevation feature, is the whole point of the OP, imho.  The earth is an ellipsoid.  The sun changes in its position in the skysphere at the observer.  These seem to be very relevant matters to consider, in addition to the lat lon elevations on the great circle from the observer to the sub solar point, and that great circle will also change as the sub solar point changes, imho.  :-)

Comment: For each time *moment*, the great circle set of data points can be reasonably reduced by ending in the direction toward the subsolar point, by calculating the approximate distance to the horizon as computed from the observer position.  In the case that the subsolar point is out over open water, ocean, find the distance to the sea level horizon.  Then there's light diffraction to consider as the sun gets lower on the horizon, depending on how accurate you want to be.  :-)

Comment: "if it is blocked by some elevation feature, is the whole point of the OP" is honestly up to them. The _blocker_ was how to find "the" (which is of course more "a") highest point between two positions, so with the power for them to fully determine that themselves given, the actual "why" and the steps necessary to address that is still theirs to figure out and implement =)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old now, but this tool exists! I was searching for exactly this same problem, and found this question, as well as my below answer.

**[This elevation calculator](http://www.mapdevelopers.com/elevation_calculator.php)** allows you to plot a straight line path (with multiple points if you like) on Google Maps and creates a graph showing the elevation across that path. You can see on the graph the highest point(s) along the path you drew!

Comment: Note that this does not cover the question, which is about the highest elevation between two points, which this service will never generate.