# Get the elevation from a point without viewing Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, elevation

I have readed [the API for elevation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) for Google Maps and what I can understands I must have the map visible to get the elevation for a point (coordinates). But almost nothing is impossible with JavaScript so I wonder now, is it possible to get the elevation from a point without viewing the map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A decade on, the Google API is for pay, with a better option being the free Open-Elevation API. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74955583/740553)

Comment: Nice! I am all for open source from few years back now and I found open-meteo.com few days ago. But to also self-hosting the whole service! open-meteo.com 0, open-elevation.com 1. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what the co-ordinates are for the point? If so, the API for elevation will return the elevation, in both JSON and XML formats. I use the following URL (albeit in PHP, it should work the same for Javascript):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/xml?sensor=false&locations=1.111,1.111.

You'll need to parse the results in JS. Switch XML out for JSON in the URL to change the result type.

**Edit:** If you use this service, you need to use it in conjunction with a Google Map as per their terms and conditions.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know it was possible to get that kind of data from Google Maps in JSON :P Many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: Heh yeah it's a pretty nice bit of kit! Enjoy :)

Comment: However, see the following note in the [documentation for the Google Elevation Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/#Limits): Note: the Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using elevation data without displaying a map for which elevation data was requested is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12).

Comment: It's no worries about the terms and conditions in my case :) I'm using Google Maps on the same page as the elevation.

Comment: As of 2018, this is a paid service, so basically useless for most.